# Static variables in global and local scope in C

Tags: c, symbols, nm

I have the following C program

```
 #include <stdio.h> 

 static int aa = 10;          

 void func(){
    static int aa = 9;
    printf("%d\n",aa);

}
int main()
{ 
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 9.

When used the nm command to see the output, I got this

```
0000000000601038 d aa
000000000060103c d aa.2286
0000000000601040 B __bss_start
0000000000601040 b completed.7585
0000000000601028 D __data_start
0000000000601028 W data_start
0000000000400460 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000004004e0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000600e18 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000601030 D __dso_handle
0000000000600e28 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000601040 D _edata
0000000000601048 B _end
00000000004005d4 T _fini
```

In the first two rows says both the variables are in the data segment, but whats that 2286 in the second row. What does it indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indicates the local static variable `aa` from the scope of `func`,  this variable is initialized only once by the dynamic loader of the system.  It is not seen from outside of the translation unit, but it is also in `data` segment, as this is where the initialization is made fast at the beginning.

The index 2286 is randomly generated, such that if you declare many variables named `aa` statically in different local scopes, to be able to distinguish each other and in the same time to keep all in `data` segment.

Comment: Are you sure it is randomly generated? I compiled it many times and nm-ed it and got the same number.

Comment: @parerariddle: it is probably generated deterministically, but the value chosen is not readily predictable.

Comment: ok fine. Is there any other way to see the symbols in an executable like nm command?